# Lost SF Story: S20 Spacecraft kidnaps people from Earth, Mars rebellion

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, space

The protagonist, a Human, flew an 'S20' Spacecraft. The area of the solar system covered was the asteroid belt to Earth, i.e. the Inner Solar System. After sleeping on this I have dredged up the following. The S20 came from Mars to Earth to kidnap people. I think the Mars colony was splitting/rebelling from earth. Mars had a secret HQ embedded in an Asteroid. I may have read this in the 1980's. The S20 may have been para-military and the pilot was male.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Raiders from the Rings](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4745728-raiders-from-the-rings)* by Alan E. Nourse?

[image: Book cover]

> "A young adult novel in which the human race is divided into the
>   Spacers and those who still remain on earth. There is a constant
>   low-level war between the two groups, with the Spacers raiding earth
>   for supplies and for women. The war turns hot in the book and three
>   teenagers, one Spacer and two from Earth, must find a way to bring
>   peace. "

However the spaceships are called *S-80* not *S20*:

> “They teach us to fly ships these days, not just pull levers,” Ben replied. “And that was one of the new S-80’s, too. Have you ever flown one? They make the old four-seaters look like cargo ships, handle so smoothly you hardly know you’re out there.”

Comment: @sueeleker.  Good guess. That would be my answer as well.

Comment: If this is Raiders from the Rings there are other plot elements worth mentioning; the spacers only have male children and have to kidnap wives from Earth, the conflict threatens to destroy the Human race, and a group of aliens who protect intelligent life seek out the protagonists and recruit them to try to stop the conflict.  If Seldon2k remembers them it is the same book.

Comment: Impressive story id!